# CPU and memory processing 100% apache

Tags: 13.04, apache2

I'm facing a big problem at my server. When i open my site many times the apache create new many threads in the server as the screenshot bellow:

[image: HTOP]

I just have tried modifying apache number threads, and change some limits in apache.conf but unsuccessfully.

Thanks for all help.

Comment: Use Nginx instead of Apache httpd *or* as reverse proxy for Apache httpd.

Comment: Could this be a malicious attack? I can think of a scenario to flood a server by requesting many copies of a server-intensive page. You would see many hits in `/var/log/apache2/access.log` if your log level is high enough.

Comment: No I guess... I've another server with the same configuration and when i make the same test (open the same page many times) apache does not create many process.